# What is Another way to use division with window function and case when statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, case-when

I want to calculate Cost per impression (CPM) in a specific time so i use this, worked, but any other way that shorter?
I use Window function to show for all row no need `GROUP BY`

```
select      (sum(case when 
time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59'
then amount_spent_usd else null end) over ()/
sum(case when time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59'
then impressions else null end) over ())*1000 
as CPM
from t1
```

i use this but not work

```
select
case when time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59'
then (sum(amount_spent_usd) over ()/ sum(impressions) over ())*1000 
else null end as cpm
from t1
```

Comment: Aggregations are done `over` windows. `case` statements are not. An `over ()` seems superfluous. You should probably post the full code, not just the subexpression.

Comment: @underscore_d no, my purpose is not use ```GROUP BY``` so I use over() to show it in all row

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the `time_of_day_viewers_time_zone` might be better stored as a time [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) rather then some string/text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filtered aggregate should do that:

```sql
(sum(amount_spent_usd) filter (where time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
                                 and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59') over ())
                                  
/ 
   
((sum(impressions) filter (where time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
                             and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59') over ()) * 1000)
```